# The script cannot be run because it is owned by a service account. Please copy or transfer the project to a valid account before running

Tags: php, google-apps-script, google-api, google-docs

I have the following issue. Through PHP, I create a copy of a Google Doc

```
$documentId = 'ID';
$googleAccountKeyFilePath = __DIR__ . '/service_key.json';
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . $googleAccountKeyFilePath);
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Some name');
$client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Docs::DOCUMENTS, \Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE]);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setAuthConfig($googleAccountKeyFilePath);
$driveService = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
$originalDocument = $driveService->files->get($documentId);
$copyDocument = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array('name' => $_GET['domain'].' Title: ' . $_GET['date_start'].' - '.$_GET['date_end']));
$newDocument = $driveService->files->copy($documentId, $copyDocument); //copying document
$newDocumentId = $newDocument->getId();
$driveService->permissions->create($newDocumentId, new \Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array('type' => 'anyone', 'role' => 'writer')));
```

The document is successfully created, and it contains an AppScript attached to the original, for example:

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Addition')
    .addItem('findSynonyms', 'findSynonyms')
    .addToUi();
}
```

But the menu item does not appear, and when manually started, there's an error:
Error
The script cannot be run because it is owned by a service account. Please copy or transfer the project to a valid account before running.

How can I fix this? What am I doing wrong? I am a bit far from all the policies of rights in App Scripts. If you can explain in more detail, I would be very grateful!"

appsscript.json:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Kiev",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Docs",
      "serviceId": "docs",
      "version": "v1"
    }, {
      "userSymbol": "Drive",
      "serviceId": "drive",
      "version": "v3"
    }]
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "DOMAIN",
    "executeAs": "USER_ACCESSING"
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

Comment: In your showing PHP script, I guess that the owner of the copied Google Document is the service account. Here, unfortunately, in the current stage, the service account cannot run Google Apps Script. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. In this case, for example, how about changing the owner to the user's account? Or, as a workaround, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/70367955

Comment: @Tanaike , you are right. Owner is service account. Can I change account owner automatic by credencials.json as example?

Comment: Thank you for replying. What is `credencials.json` of `Owner is service account. Can I change account owner automatic by credencials.json as example?`?

Comment: @Tanaike , here: `$googleAccountKeyFilePath = __DIR__ . '/service_key.json';` i use service account auth. Can I create copy of document and automatic assign my account as owner of this document?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I can't understand the difference between `service_key.json` of `$googleAccountKeyFilePath = __DIR__ . '/service_key.json';` and `credencials.json` of `Owner is service account. Can I change account owner automatic by credencials.json as example?`. About `Can I create copy of document and automatic assign my account as owner of this document?`, do you want to create a new Google Document using OAuth2 with your account? First, I would like to correctly understand your expected result.

Comment: For example, if you want to create a Google Document by copying using the service account and want to transfer the owner to the user's account, I think that this can be achieved. In this case, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/75935222 This thread is for Python. But, I guessed that it might help understand the method for achieving this. If this thread might not be useful, I apologize.